# Want to allign image between paragraph

Tags: css

I'm stuck in the center alignment of image between 2 paragraph column-wise through css only so if anyone has a solution of this problem so please tell me.

HTML

```html
  <div class="container">
    <p class='first'>
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
    </p>
    <img src='https://placehold.it/200x200'/>
    <p class='second'>
         Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
    </p>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: please show a MVCE with actual markup and style, not a screenshot.

Comment: Image doesn't help to solve the issue. Post your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to help without some markup, but you can't float centre, so it would be best to do something like this;

```
<style>
    .grid-three{
        width:33.33%;
        display:block;
        float:left;
    }
</style>

<p class="grid-three">blah blah...</p>
<img class="grid-three" src="blah" />
<p class="grid-three">blah blah...</p>
```

This is a very simple configuration - you may want to experiment to get this working in a nicer way responsively.

You could also swap the img for a div containing the image, to allow the image to keep it's original size, and you could also try applying separate widths (like 40% to each p and 20% to the img block).

Test out some ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps for you:

HTML code:

```
<div id="footer">
<span>Text</span>
<span><img src="http://www.klm.com/jobs/nl/images/icon_flight_32x32_tcm701-312701.gif" /></span>
<span>More text</span>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#footer {
width: 100%;
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
background: gray;
}
#footer span {
display: table-cell;
}
#footer span:nth-child(2) { text-align: center; }
#footer span:last-child { text-align: right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.row > div{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 30%;
      vertical-align: middle;
    
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
     
As a side note: for those using npm and looking for a quick, reliable and ready-made solution there's lodash.random that can be easily required with a super small footprint (it will import just the method itself and not the whole lodash).
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97150&w=150&h=150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
    
As a side note: for those using npm and looking for a quick, reliable and ready-made solution there's lodash.random that can be easily required with a super small footprint (it will import just the method itself and not the whole lodash).
    </div>
    </div>
    

</body>
</html>
```